# To find $\frac {(\frac {x}{p}+\frac {y}{q})}{p^2+q^2} $.

Tags: complex-numbers

If $ Z=x-iy $ and $ Y=p+iq $ is a cube root of $ Z $, then, what Is the value of $$\frac {(\frac {x}{p}+\frac {y}{q})}{p^2+q^2} $$.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When is this due?

Comment: Smelling homework.....

Comment: Why is your friend not asking the question ? Knowing what he/she already tried, it would be easier to explain directly to him/her.

Comment: Ah, the infamous "a friend of mine asked me this" topos...

Comment: Being truthful is bad sometimes. Haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $z=x-iy$ and $z^{\frac{1}{3}} = p+iq\Rightarrow z = (p+iq)^3$

So $$x-iy = p^3+i^3q^3+3piq(p+iq) = p^3-iq^3+3ip^2q-3pq^2$$

So $x=p^3-3pq^2$ and $y=q^3-3p^2q$

So $$\frac{x}{p}+\frac{y}{q} = p^2-3q^2+q^2-3p^2=-2(p^2+q^2)$$

So $$\frac{\frac{x}{p}+\frac{y}{q}}{p^2+q^2} = -2$$